# White space when using img in a div

Tags: html, css

My current css is

```css
.container {
display: block;
width: 400px;
height: auto;
padding: 0px 0px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: black 1px solid;
}
.container img {
width: 100%;
}
```

And html is

```
<div class="container">
<img src="http://67.media.tumblr.com/15b26a66682a68facad249bd442ced38/tumblr_nw48hrdLfp1sikueao2_1280.jpg">
</div>
```

[image]

Here is the result, how do i get rid of the white space below the image?

Comment: try to add "display: inline-block;" for .container img.

Comment: Also using this `<img src="#"><img>` you are creating two `<img>` tag. Maybe it is a typo :)

Comment: @WilliamMartins typo in OP the actuall code is '<img src="http://67.media.tumblr.com/15b26a66682a68facad249bd442ced38/tumblr_nw48hrdLfp1sikueao2_1280.jpg">'

Comment: @dovia, this typo was in the non-edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hello apply display block to image

```
div img {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default display for `img` elements is `inline` and that white space below image is space for descenders on letters like j, y, g... You can fix that by adding `vertical-align: top`

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: black 1px solid;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```